# How can I set the 'text' property in Appium's inspector on Android using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I need each visible UI component (widget in Flutter) to be distinguishable and have both `accessibility-id` and `text` properties when being inspected using Appium's Inspector. I also need both these properties to be different.

I've been using Flutter's Semantics widget to attempt to achieve this but have yet to find a way to set the `text` property.

Let's say I want the accessibility-id to be set to 'label' and text to be set to 'textContent'.

```
Semantics(
   label: 'label',
   child: Text('textContent'),
)
```

This is what the code above results in when inspecting using Appium Inspector:
[image]

If I then set the excludeSemantics property to true:

```
Semantics(
   excludeSemantics: true,
   label: 'label',
   child: Text('textContent'),
)
```

The accessibility-id gets set correctly but still no text is available in the Appium Inspector:
[image]

I've also played around Semantics' 'value' property which works well on iOS but on Android it just appends it to the start of the accessibility-id:

```
Semantics(
   excludeSemantics: true,
   label: 'label',
   value: 'value',
   child: Text('textContent'),
)
```

Result:
[image]

I'm unsure if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible. If anyone knows of a solution using Semantics or any other alternative that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this question? I'm facing the same issue now. Hope to hear from your soon bro

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem with Appium, but why not just use the [`semanticsLabel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/semanticsLabel.html) property directly?

```dart
Text(
  'An error occurred',
  semanticsLabel: 'error-occurred',
)
```

Comment: This does not work for setting the 'text' value.